# Missing Push Notification Entitlement app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, provisioning-profile, entitlements

I got a email from itunes connect with the following message:

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
>   API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
>   app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
>   Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>   If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
>   developer for information on removing the API.

But here is the funny thing I'm not using notifications it all. This what I have tried:

1.-I delete all the provisioning profiles manually and download them using Xcode (didn't work)

2.-I delete all the provisioning profiles manually and download from the apple developer portal (didn't work)

3.- I add it "DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS=1" to build settings (didn't work)

[image]
When I try to upload the app to itunes connect using Xcode is showing the provisioning profile XC:* I don't know if this has something to do with the Entitlement missing.

I as I said this app is not using push notifications on any way shape or form.

I'll really appreciate any pointers or work around this issue.

Comment: Do you what the problem is?

Comment: I just got that email too and I don't use push notifications. Doesn't sound like it affects the submission process though.

Comment: Do you think is just an issue with the submissions?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement

Comment: @jherg As I have mention before I'm not using push notifications. The link you mentions is to configure push notifications

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug from apple validator. Its coming from last 1 week. Read this blog
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11704#47536

If your application does not use notification then leave as it is. Apple will approve the app.

Answer (score 3):

- Are you using any libraries/frameworks/cocoapods? Maybe you have an analytics module (Crashlytics? Fabric.io?) that is registering your app for push notifications. Remove those and try again.
- Do a search on `registerUserNotificationSettings` and see if anything pops up. If you're calling that API, the compiler is picking this up as a push notification app.