# Can I use Scial.framework without Push Notifications?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, social-framework

In my app I use Social.framework to post on facebook. When I sent my app for review to Apple I got this reply.

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "****". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the
>   following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
>   API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
>   app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
>   Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>   If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
>   developer for information on removing the API.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

Has anybody any idea of what I should do? I don't use push notifications, I just post to Facebook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing Push Notification Entitlement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Social framework** provides simple interface for accessing the user’s social media accounts. Like twitter , Facebook , Sina Weibo etc.

And to use the social framework you don't need Push notifications.

As you said you didn't use push notifications, then go to developer.apple.com and check that your APP ID must not enabled the **Push Notifications** and check your provisioning profiles.

And if you are using some kind of library or API which may be registered with Apple push notifications then make your you have make the proper settings for enabling the PUSH NOTIFICATIONS.