# Push notification capabilities ios

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, capability

We have implemented push notifications in our iOS app, and it seems to be working fine, regardless of whether we set the push notification capability on or off. So my question is: What does that capability controll? See screenshot for where we set the capability.

Thanks.

Claus

[image]

Comment: If you using/asking for push notification, you need to check it. It will work without it. But you will be rejected on binary upload for iTunes Connect.

Comment: On Xcode 7, it is determined by push settings in your AppID. On Xcode 8, it is determined by entitlement files. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266891/xcode-8-push-notification-capabilities-and-entitlements-file-setting

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add the entitlement, your app won't pass the AppStore submission.

An error similar to the following will appear (cf. [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement)):

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register
>   with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's
>   entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement.

Comment: Strange, I submit my app with notification service without reject, I didn't turn on the Push Notification Capability.