# Xcode 8 binary is not Showing on itunesconnect for Review

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode8

I have made Binary file from Xcode 8 and upload to App Store through Application Loader(3.6). Also it is submitted successfully with pop up. But the Binary is not showing in iTunesConnect since it crosses 19 hour yet it is not showing in itunesconnect.

Please Help me out from this situation

@update
Here is my Plist file
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced same issue. I was using client's account and submitted builds. I got `Upload Successful` popup but builds were not shown.
This happens because there are privacy policy changes for `iOS 10` so that we have to add some permissions in `Info.plist`. 
Refer this post: [iOS 10 - Changes in asking permissions of Camera, microphone and Photo Library causing application to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498275/ios-10-changes-in-asking-permissions-of-camera-microphone-and-photo-library-c)

If you don't add these permissions or if you added permission but missed string value of it, your binary will not displayed on store. In this case apple will send email to `Agent of developer account`. So check that email. You might got email with subject something like this `**iTunes Connect: Your app APP NAME (Apple ID: APP ID) has one or more issues**`

So try to fix these and resubmit build. Once your build displays in activity tab with Processing status, then you can submit it for review after processing.

Also you have to add `.entitlements` file in case if your app contains push `notifications and APNS` setup. Refer this: [xcode 8 push notification capabilities and entitlements file setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266891/xcode-8-push-notification-capabilities-and-entitlements-file-setting)

This is weird issue and apple should throw error while validating it but they are not doing it. You can check above and fix the issue.

Comment: Hey Pushkraj, I have already added permission for Camera & Photos in Plist file.

Comment: Can you share Plist tags for those permissions? Right click and click on Open As Source Code and copy it.

Comment: Check this to declare Privacy Permission Settings in Info. https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html

Comment: /Users/nikhilchawade/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-11-30 at 3.36.21 PM.png

Comment: @iPhoneDev You can't add screenshot like this. Just share me code like 

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>YOUR MESSAGE</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>YOUR MESSAGE</string>

Comment: <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>use to browse the photo</string><key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string></string> I Have added like this previously

Comment: @iPhoneDev Got the issue,
whenever you add Privacy-XXXXXX, you have to add value for it

So add "App wants to use camera" next to "Privacy - Camera Usage Description"

And submit build again.

And make sure you increased build number before uploading app, otherwise it will show you error of "Redundant Binary Uploaded"

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have added Key & value as you said. But still binary is not coming in iTunesconnect. nearly it 45 minutes when I uploaded binary on Application Loader.

Comment: Can you please check whether your agent got email regarding same?
Agent email is same email from with you are login to developer.apple.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129444/discussion-between-iphonedev-and-pushkraj).

Comment: Perfect. Lets continue