# iTunes connect build submission issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, appstore-approval

[Build prolem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sq6i.png)

Hi i am uploading since a week but every time i am facing an issue.When i upload the build from Xcode it will sucessfully uploaded but in iTunes it will be displayed as screenshot.after 5 Min. it will be also disappered. So what is an issue in that? Anyone resolve this?

Comment: You need to check mail after uploading the app on iTunes, it will help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: pls try to upload using application loader.
and pls delete and  reinstall both provisioning profile ,Adhoc and appStore on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screen shot shows that upload the build successfully to itunesconnect.You will an email alert from store for successfull upload. It will take approximate 10 to 15minutes times for processing. Once this processing completed. This build will show under the Builds. Select the build version and submit to App Store.

Reference screen shot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883932/xcode-8-binary-is-not-showing-on-itunesconnect-for-review/40884634#40884634) post. I answered this long back, and you can fix issue. Read it in details.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Please follow these steps :

1. Launch Application Loader.
2. In the top menu bar, click Application Loader > Preferences.
3. Choose Advanced.
4. Under Transfer Protocol, deselect Aspera.
5. Close the Preferences window and proceed with the delivery.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply but when i do this it will get error in application loader