# Not able to see uploaded appliction from xcode to itunes Connect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have apple account id with Agent role. 
which shows in Xcode preferences accounts

### Team                 |   Role  |

XYZ Ltd              |   Agent |
Name (Personal team) |   User  |

with this, I have created app store provisioning and distributed certificate. Then I archive the app and uploaded to the app store. I got uploaded done message popup.

followed [the linked steps](https://subodhnpushpak.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/deploying-ios-apps-without-udid-to-beta-testers-using-testflight-beta-testing/)

SignedIn to iTunes connect with same apple id and I can see the Role as Admin over there

In iTunes connect I have done all the steps till creating the build and adding info to it.
But I am not seeing my build which I uploaded through Xcode. Even I tried with Application loader also. still facing the same issue. I am getting the status as prepared for submission with the version I have created.

Is this problem because I gave Agent account apple id or anything I am missing

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883932/xcode-8-binary-is-not-showing-on-itunesconnect-for-review/40884634#40884634

I answered this and it will surely solve your problem.

Comment: Everything is correct, the problem may be with some latest Project Settings you might be missing to add in your build, the build is getting rejected, although apple sends email for the error you might be having for the build and check the actual agents emails, apple must have sent errors you might be having with the build, correct them and upload again.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got mail with some error,so I resolved those and resubmitted and it works fine