# "Fix Issue" under Capabilities invalidates my provisioning profiles. And push not working otherwise

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My iOS push notification stopped working so when I went to my member center I regenerated my provisioning profile for development and distribution and they became active. Still no push notifications were showing up on my app. So when I went to the `Capabilities` tab in XCode I saw that the `Add the "Push Notifications" entitlement to your App ID`

[image]

So clicking this doesn't help it just invalidates my provisioning profile. And when I re generate and re download them then choose them this warning comes back and still no push notifications.

Comment: It is already answered here.Kindly go through it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement

Comment: i am  looking the accepted answer says to delete all the profiles from local machine, do they mean keychain?

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem. I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I am facing the same problem too with xcode 8.1... I can't register into parse

Answer (score 0):

Check if you app's Bundle ID is same as in the certificates.

If nothing went well try removing all the certificates from the keychain access and provisioning profiles from iPhone Configuration Utilities and re-installing them.

Comment: where is iPhone Configuration Utilities?

Comment: Install it from here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1aoeoqu7eobe6mv/iPhone%20Configuration%20Utility.dmg?dl=0

Comment: what is its purpose? never used it before

Comment: It shows provisioning profiles and devices added to those certificates.