# Missing Push Notification Entitlement even if app does not contain push notification enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have created an app which doesn't use Push notification. In the Capabilities section of the app target Push notification is OFF. The app ID, development and distribution provisioning profiles does not contain Push notification as enabled services. But still i receive below email from iTunes whenever i upload binary to iTunes

> **Missing Push Notification Entitlement** - Your app appears to register
>   with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's
>   entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your
>   app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is
>   enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit
>   after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that
>   includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. Xcode 8 does not
>   automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning
>   profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this
>   entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's
>   Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your
>   entitlements file. For more information, see
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.

What could have been gone wrong.

Comment: Does your app include any code that attempts to register a device for notifications? That's how I read that message.

Comment: @toddg I have not added any code of push notification. But still getting the issue :(

Comment: Hmmm, strange. Maybe try looking through all the responses on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement

Answer (score 4):

This is the equivalent of a warning, not an error.
However, if you want to remove the warning message, you can simply set Push notification to ON (even though you do not use them), and you won't receive this email on your next build. This will generate an entitlements file.

However, the people in this forum seem to have gotten their apps approved despite the warning (as of September 10, 2015):
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15880