# IOS builds successfully, but can't deploy to store because Missing Push Notification Entitlement, App does NOT use Push Notifications

Tags: ios, react-native, deployment

I've double checked in the IOS Provision Profile(Distribution) to make sure that Push Notifications are enabled even though this app doesn't use push notifications.

[image]

Here is my current build settings page: 
[image]

And here is the general settings page:

[image]

What else do I need to check/change so that I can get the app deployed to the iOS store/stop receiving this notification when I upload.

Comment: check capabilities in xcode?

Comment: I double checked capabilities.  It's currently turned off.  Should it be turned on?

Comment: I turned it on and immediately got a red exclamation mark that said "Your app requires a provisioning profile  with Push Notifications feature"

Comment: @VK1 [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement) it might help you.