# not able to receive push notification on ios device

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I am implementing react-native-firebase to my app
i have followed steps from official document(https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios) as well as some other similar blogs (https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591),

but I am not able to receive any notification on my real device,

I followed all steps excepts generating key's, ID, and provisioning as I had already these while publishing my app

i have tried to send a notification from firebase console like below 
[image]

and from postman

[image: Screen Shot 2019-03-23 at 6.53.33 PM]

it shows succeed but no notification on the real device

i have also tried with oneSignal it was showing some apns 3000 error with my device as below

[image]

I have tried below solutions like

1 changing search header path

2 link binary with library

3 re-creating provisioning profile 
but nothing worked

I am expecting to just receive my first push notification I am 
 struggling from last three days please help.

**the step i follow to integrate firebase are below,**

1 Create ios Firebase Project and add the googleservice-info.plist into my project on the final step firebase was able to connect with my app as below SS
[image]

2 Install Native Firebase Core and Firebase Messaging Libraries (pods)

3 Install and Link react native firebase lib

4 i had already a key for APNs generated so i upload the .p8 file in firebase messaging setting with key ID and Team ID

5 i had already provisioning profiles which i generated at the time of app publish

6 finally i add pushnotification and remote capabilities and add some code in appdelegate h&m files as suggested in documentation

Comment: You need to add "APNs Authentication Key" downloaded from Apple Developer account, under 'Cloud Messaging" Section on Firebase Console.Make sure you bundleID for your Apps Matches the one with the certificates.Let me know if you have already followed the above steps.
Also if possible, please share the specific steps that you followed

Comment: I have uploaded the p8 file on my firebase project, I also downloaded provisioning profile for both development and production

Comment: hi – Himanshu G I have added the steps I followed in my original question at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

Updating XCode from 9.4 to 10.1 helped me to solve my issue

the issue was with some of my provisioning profile downloaded earlier

I had already published the same code with some UI  changes with XCode 9.4 but I never receive any suggestions/warning from apple

but this time when I publish the app with updated XCode 10.1 I received below email from Apple which gave me the right direction to find the solutions

[image]

then i follow the below answer 
[Missing Push Notification Entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement)

and solve my issue by delete the all Provisioning profile on my local machine, then re-download and install the Provisioning profile from the Provisioning Portal.